# number of ways to write $p^e$ as sum of two positive integer squares

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, gaussian-integers

I am reading the proof of the sum of two square function, and I got stuck at this little segment

> let $p^e$ be a prime factor of n, $p \equiv 1 \pmod4$, there are $e+1$ positive integer solutions (x,y) tuple of the equation $p^e = x^2+y^2$

I know that Fermat proved that $p$ can be expressed uniquely as $x^2+y^2$ and $y^2+x^2$, and I also know that $(x^2+y^2)(a^2+b^2) = (ax+by)^2+(ay-bx)^2$

the website I am reading suggests that given $p = x^2+y^2$ all the solution is of the form$$p^e = (x^2+y^2)^i(y^2+x^2)^{e-i}, i\in\{0,1,,,e\}$$

but I have no idea how to prove that **first** these solutions do not overlap and **second** they cover every single possible solutions

my intuition is that since Fermat provides me with the base case(e=1), should I use induction?...but I don't even know how to show it cover ever solution for e=2

thanks for the help

Comment: This is not quite right. There are $2$ positive solutions of $x^2+y^2=25$.

Answer (score 1):

If $p = a^2 + b^2$ and $p^e = c^2 + d^2$, then $p^{e+1} = (a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2)$.  Do you know how to write $(a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2)$ as the sum of two squares?